# Yii2 leftJoin() not working with find()

Tags: php, yii2

"photo_1" is the column of the "anmt_photo" and "title" is the column of the "anmt" table but when I use

```
<?= $anmt->title; ?>
```

it is working but

```
<?= $anmt->photo_1; ?>
```

not working

Here is my code :

```
$anmt_t = Anmt::find()
  ->select('*')
  ->leftJoin('anmt_photo', 'anmt_photo.photo_key = anmt.anmt_key')
  ->leftJoin('anmt_categ', 'anmt_categ.categ_key = anmt.anmt_key');

$count = $anmt_t->count();

// create a pagination object with the total count
$pagination = new Pagination(['defaultPageSize' => 20, 'totalCount' => $count]);


// limit the query using the pagination and retrieve the articles
$anmts = $anmt_t->offset($pagination->offset)
    ->limit($pagination->limit)
    ->all();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add column names of other tables to:-

```
->select(['anmt.*','anmt_photo.photo_1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$anmt_t = Anmt::find()
   ->select(['anmt_photo.photo_1', 'anmt.title']) // and other fields...
   ->leftJoin('anmt_photo', 'anmt_photo.photo_key = anmt.anmt_key')
   ->leftJoin('anmt_categ', 'anmt_categ.categ_key = anmt.anmt_key');
```

if you are loading many ActiveRecords, you may find it more efficient to declare relations and use [`joinWith()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequery.html#joinWith()-detail) or [`with()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activequerytrait.html#with()-detail), rather than [`leftJoin()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#leftJoin()-detail) to gather your data.

more reading in the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)